# Rerun on failed hosts only from workflow and inventory

Tags: ansible

I have written a playbook to do a service check, for this example lets say to check if port 110 and 143 is listening - Dovecot service. 
My inventory contains 16 hosts. IP's .1 - .16 respectively.

What I aim to achieve is: If dovecot is up do nothing however if it is off do X.
The issue I am having is - If dovecot or the ports are not listening it does not restart the service on that failed host alone but all the hosts within the inventory

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
- name: Check IMAP status
      shell: echo exit | telnet 127.0.0.1 143 | grep Connected
      register: imapconn
      ignore_errors: true
- name: Restart failed services
      service:
        name: dovecot
        state: restarted
         when: imapconn.stdout_lines != "Connected to 127.0.0.1."
```

Example playbook above

EDIT::
Could I not achieve the below:

```
 hosts:
 - "{{ item }}"
 gather_facts: true

 tasks:

   - name: Check IMAP status

     shell: echo exit | telnet 127.0.0.1 143 | grep Connected

     register: imapconn

     ignore_errors: true

   - debug:

           msg: var={{hostvars.item }}

     with_items: "{{ groups['devgroup1'] }}"

 with_items: 

   - "{{ groups['mailstorage'] }}"
```

Servers 1 - 16 are in mailstorage, want to sequentially do service check 1 on .1 then once completed move to 2 and so on until end of inventory

Comment: My indentation is in line with that of the answer. My issue is pertaining to host specific tasks based off first not calling it again.
When indentation is fine. 

Was mixed up when copying it over to the question, my apologies

Comment: This a question and answer site. The question is posted above, the answer to the immediate problem is under the dup-target and is "fix the indentation". You don't need to apologise, you can edit the question and as the answer won't be applicable anymore, I could reopen the question. However, after you fix the indentation, we'll move to the second problem and I'll look for another duplicate question in which someone compares a list to a string and asks why they don't match. ... Ok, I just found one and attached.

Comment: You could not "*achieve the below* because the code you posted in the edit is not an Ansible code; it is your own invention. Moreover, this has nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: Quite correct - it is pseudo code to paint an idea of what is desired to be achieved. 
Will keep it relevant though and post another question

Comment: Check [RETRY_FILES_ENABLED](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html)